# How to apply .replace() inside a column in a pandas data frame to clean data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame where I want to replace all the values that are not numeric in one column for ""

The error I'm getting in my code is the following:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '690,276.00'
```

Since I'm trying to convert all values into float so I can do internal operations with them.

Part of my cleaning data frame code looks like this:

```
    # Cleaning:              
df_clean = df_read[~(df_read['Ratio of Similarity (Gray)'] <= .2)]
print(df_clean, 'clean 1: Eliminate Ratio of similarity less than 0.2')
df_clean_2 = df_clean.dropna(subset=['buybox_price'])  
print(df_clean_2, 'clean 2: Eliminate Nan Buybox Prices')
df_clean_2 = df_clean_2.replace(",", "").replace('', '').astype({'product_ranking':'float64'})
df_clean_3 = df_clean_2[~(df_clean_2['product_ranking'] >= 5000000)]
print(df_clean_3, 'clean 3: Eliminate Product Ranking + than 5.000.000')
df_clean_4 = df_clean_3[~(df_clean_3['buybox_price'] <= 6)]
print(df_clean_4, 'clean 4: Eliminate Buybox Price less than 6$')
# Save Cleaned File
path_file = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'csv/amazon_product_comparator.csv')
df_hc = df_clean_4.to_csv(path_file)
```

The error can be found in the line:

```
df_clean_3 = df_clean_2[~(df_clean_2['product_ranking'] >= 5000000)]
    print(df_clean_3, 'clean 3: Eliminate Product Ranking + than 5.000.000')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED to include a working example.**

I have made an example with string type numeric data. I have also include a poorly formatted string number **1,002,*8320**.

The code below will convert the numbers in the format of digits and digits with commas to floats, and convert all other strings to NaN. I have used a regular expression to replace commas with blanks.

The NaN must be used over "" since the comparison operator will not work on strings

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

# example data frame
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['1', '2000000000'],
                    ['2', '1,002,*8320'],
                    ['3', '1,000,000']],
                   columns = ['idx','product_ranking'])
# Remove Commas
df2['product_ranking'] = df2['product_ranking'].map(lambda x: re.sub('[,]*' , '', x))

# Remove Convert strings that are numeric into floats.
df2['product_ranking'] = df2['product_ranking'].map(lambda x: float(x) if x.isnumeric() else np.nan)

#Comparison is working
df2['product_ranking'] > 100000000
```

Comment: Sure! there you have some code, there is the line that gives the error

Comment: Some of them are in the correct format, the errors I have found come form commas and dots

Comment: There shouldn't be other types of variables. Actually those values are supposed to be only integers

Comment: See if this might do the trick. import re; df_clean2['product_ranking'].map(lambda x: float(re.sub('[,\s]*' , '', x)))